# SQL - missing keyword in case when syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting this error message

> missing keyword

Any suggestions? thanks

```
CASE WHEN 
     substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4)>=0 
         and substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4) < 4000 
         then 'ASSET'
ELSE CASE WHEN 
         substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4)>=4000 
            and substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4) < 8000 
         then 'LIABILITY' 
ELSE CASE WHEN
          substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4)>=8000 
           and substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4) < 9000 
          then 'OFF BALANCE SHEET ASSET' 
ELSE CASE WHEN 
         substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4)>=9000 
         and substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4) < 10000 
         then 'OFF BALANCE SHEET LIABILITY' end as ASSET_TYPE,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using more "CASE" word in your case statement. Remove "ELSE CASE" after each "Then". [Refer this Oracle Documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php)

```
CASE WHEN 
     substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4)>=0 
         and substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4) < 4000 
         then 'ASSET'
     WHEN 
         substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4)>=4000 
            and substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4) < 8000 
         then 'LIABILITY' 
     WHEN
          substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4)>=8000 
           and substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4) < 9000 
          then 'OFF BALANCE SHEET ASSET' 
    WHEN 
         substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4)>=9000 
         and substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4) < 10000 
         then 'OFF BALANCE SHEET LIABILITY' 
 END as ASSET_TYPE,
```

The general syntax will be

```
CASE  
   WHEN col = 1 THEN 'Active' 
   WHEN col = 2 THEN 'Inactive' 
   WHEN col = 3 THEN 'Terminated' 
END AS StatusText
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is  :

```
case when substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4)>=0 and substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4) < 4000 then 'ASSET'
     when substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4)>=4000 and substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4) < 8000 then 'LIABILITY' 
     when substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4)>=8000 and substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4) < 9000 then 'OFF BALANCE SHEET ASSET' 
     when substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4)>=9000 and substr(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO,length(M1.M_GL_LINE_NO - 4),4) < 10000 then 'OFF BALANCE SHEET LIABILITY' 
else '' end as ASSET_TYPE,
```

thanks